# Extremely slow wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cgi, vps

I have a big problem with my website. 2 days ago it started to have high response times, slow menus, etc...

When I checked the apache log I saw this:

```
[Tue Nov 15 08:03:02.483834 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 5936] [client
90.164.184.119:35610] End of script output before headers: ea-php56,
referer:     http://m.facebook.com/
[Tue Nov 15 08:03:03.528154 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 6856] [client
90.171.139.86:55239] End of script output before headers: ea-php56,
referer: http://m.facebook.com/

[Tue Nov 15 08:02:48.314544 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 6645] [client
94.143.78.239:54843] AH01215: PHP Deprecated:  Automatically populating
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini
and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line
0:/usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/ea-php56, referer:
http://www.url.es/moreurl....
```

Apache generates this lines of code each 4 or 5 seconds, i think may be this te cause of the slow server (VPS SSD).
I tried to set `always_populate_raw_post_data` to `-1`, and the performance has improved, but not even close what it has to be.

The website is based on wordpress, and I hope someone has experience with this issue...

Thanks in advance

Comment: There seems to have some issue with facebook, do you fetch some data from facebook on your website?

Comment: Yes, only facebook píxel, but i think the problem hasn't come from there, because of this message "End of script output before headers: ea-php56"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Finally I did set up "always_populate_raw_post_data to -1" and I reinstalled WP Supercache on WP and all it's fine now.